# Change css from selection after getting start and end position

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following code to get the start and end position of a selection relative to an element:

```
function getSelectionCharOffsetsWithin(element) {
    var start = 0, end = 0;
    var sel, range, priorRange;
    if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
        range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
        priorRange = range.cloneRange();
        priorRange.selectNodeContents(element);
        priorRange.setEnd(range.startContainer, range.startOffset);
        start = priorRange.toString().length;
        end = start + range.toString().length;
    } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" &&
            (sel = document.selection).type != "Control") {
        range = sel.createRange();
        priorRange = document.body.createTextRange();
        priorRange.moveToElementText(element);
        priorRange.setEndPoint("EndToStart", range);
        start = priorRange.text.length;
        end = start + range.text.length;
    }
    return {
        start: start,
        end: end
    };
}
```

How can I change the css property of that selection with the start and end position?, something like:

```
var data-start = data.start;
var data-end = data.end;
$('#document').css('background-color', 'blue'); //// but I only want to affect the selection I did before.
```

note: I retrieve the start and end position from mysql.

I need something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/KcX6A/3534/
But instead of an input the element must be a div

Comment: If you are just trying to change the colour of selected text, you can do it directly with css: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/s/selection/

Comment: @Pete I store the selection range in mysql, then after retrieving that range I want to change the css.